# Cover Image and First Page Overlap

Tags: memoir, covers

I'm extremely new to LaTeX and learning on my own, so I apologize if this is an obvious question. In my document, I'm using a pdf image as the first cover page, and additional pages after that. I found out how to include a cover image from previous questions here, but the cover is overlapping the first page - acting like a background behind the text. Images and text on the first page are superimposed over the cover.

I'm constructing the document by having a main file and then \include-ing each section, including the cover page. The "cover" section is the following:

```
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{textblock*}{400mm}(0mm,0mm)
\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{coverimage.pdf}
\end{textblock*}
```

And this is the document info I'm using:

```
\documentclass[]{memoir}
\usepackage[left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{charter}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
```

I've tried not using include and just putting the cover image command on the "main" document but that doesn't work either. How can I fix this, and what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using `\chapter`, `\section` et al. to add text to your document?

Try

```
\documentclass[oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage[left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{charter}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\usepackage{lipsum}% remove this line

\begin{document}
\frontmatter

\aliaspagestyle{chapter}{empty}
\chapter{}
\begin{textblock*}{400mm}(0mm,0mm)
\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{coverimage.pdf}
\end{textblock*}

\mainmatter

\aliaspagestyle{chapter}{plain}
\chapter{}
\lipsum[1-5]% remove this line

\end{document}
```

You'll find useful information in the [`memoir class` Manual](http://www.tex.ac.uk/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf)

Comment: I was not using \chapter and \section - it's a pretty simple, 3 part, 18 page document, but your answer helped and now my document is displaying everything as it should. Thanks!

Comment: If it is a simple document, consider using the `article` document class which provides you with a simpler framework for shorter documents.